# Why did compiler alert undefined?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Why does the compiler say this?

> ```
> Argument of type '{ kind: "available"; | { kind: "notAvailable"; } | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Schedule'.
>   Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Schedule'.
> ```

it is absolutely unable to put 'undefined'  in availableTimeShiftsByHoursTables

```
     let availableTimeShiftsByHoursTables: Schedule[] = new Array();
    scheduleInfo.map(element => {
      if (element.schedules.get(targetDate)) {
        availableTimeShiftsByHoursTables.push(
          element.schedules.get(targetDate)
        );
      }
    });
```

Comment: Can you try assigning `element.schedules.get(targetDate)` to a variable rather than calling it twice?

Comment: You might be need to check the existence of targetDate before getting it. I am guessing this is a `Map` type so you could do `if (element.schedules.has(targetDate))` and then add it to the array

Comment: Seems that `element.schedules.get()` returns `{ kind: "available"; | { kind: "notAvailable"; } | undefined`. But typeof `Schedule` is `{ kind: "available"; | { kind: "notAvailable"; }`. Please provide `element.schedules.get()` definition

Comment: Please consider editing the code here to constitute a [mcve] as described in the guidelines for [ask].  Preferably something we can drop into our own IDE to demonstrate the issue you're seeing and only the issue you're seeing.  Otherwise all we can do is guess and that's not as likely to get you a usable answer.  Good luck!